# This java tutorial is WRONG?

Tags: java, object

I am trying to learn objects and classes in java and an online tutorial is giving me code which I cant compile/run on eclipse.

When I compile the program after saving the class it gives me the error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

The method setAge(int) is undefined for the type Puppy

The method getAge() is undefined for the type Puppy 
at Puppy.main(Puppy.java:23)*

```
public class Puppy{

       int puppyAge;

       public Puppy(String name){
      // This constructor has one parameter, name.
      System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name ); 
   }
   public setAge( int age ){
       puppyAge = age;
   }

   public getAge( ){
       System.out.println("Puppy's age is :" + puppyAge ); 
       return puppyAge;
   }
   public static void main(String []args){
      /* Object creation */
      Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "tommy" );

      /* Call class method to set puppy's age */
      myPuppy.setAge( 2 );

      /* Call another class method to get puppy's age */
      myPuppy.getAge( );

      /* You can access instance variable as follows as well */
      System.out.println("Variable Value :" + myPuppy.puppyAge ); 
   }
}
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

(the code is in the middle of the page)

It is a constructor class program. **There should be no return type.**

Comment: yep the tutorial is wrong..

Comment: You seem to be using Eclipse. Go to the menu Window, then choose *Show View*, then *Problems*. This view should always be opened. It contains all the errors and warnings from the compiler. Don't launch the program while there is an error in this view. And read the error messages associated with the errors: they contain meaningful information.

Comment: BTW, in real code, those comments should _not_ be there. The purpose of code comments is to explain why, not how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why it does not work?

You have to add return types to `getAge()` and `setAge()`.

[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html) notes that method declaration should follow this format:

MethodModifiers(optional) TypeParameters(optional) Result MethodDeclarator Throws(optional)

Relax, lets look at this slowly:

- MethodModifiers(optional) - You can mark each method as private/public/protected. If you omit this parameter method is package. There are few more modifiers, but these are most interesting for You now
- TypeParameters(optional) - It is about generic methods. You can safely skip this one now
- Result - This one is important. Every method must explicitly say what it returns. This was missing in Your example.
- MethodDeclarator - name of Your method.
- Throws(optional) - if Your method will throw exceptions You have to write it here. For now You can safely skip it.

[image]

### Just show me the working code!

```
public class Puppy{

    int puppyAge;

    public Puppy(String name){
        // This constructor has one parameter, name.
        System.out.println("Passed Name is :" + name );
    }
    public void setAge( int age ){
        puppyAge = age;
    }

    public int getAge( ){
        System.out.println("Puppy's age is :" + puppyAge );
        return puppyAge;
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
      /* Object creation */
        Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy( "tommy" );

      /* Call class method to set puppy's age */
        myPuppy.setAge( 2 );

      /* Call another class method to get puppy's age */
        myPuppy.getAge( );

      /* You can access instance variable as follows as well */
        System.out.println("Variable Value :" + myPuppy.puppyAge );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You are (or, tutorial)  missing return type in method signature.

```
public setAge( int age ){
       puppyAge = age;
   }

   public getAge( ){
       System.out.println("Puppy's age is :" + puppyAge ); 
       return puppyAge;
   }
```

should be

```
public void setAge( int age ){
       puppyAge = age;
   }

   public int getAge( ){
       System.out.println("Puppy's age is :" + puppyAge ); 
       return puppyAge;
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

you are missing return types for your methods.

```
 public setAge( int age ){
```

should be

```
   public void setAge( int age ){
```

and

```
   public getAge( ){
```

should be

```
   public int getAge( ){
```

Answer (score 4):

Your methods do not state what (type) is returned. Change them to this:

```
 public void setAge(int age) { ... }
 public int getAge() { ... }
```

The documentation lists six parts of a Java method:

1. Modifiers—such as public, private, and others you will learn about later.
2. **The return type**—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value. (*You missed this*)
3. The method name—the rules for field names apply to method names as well, but the convention is a little different.
4. The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, (). If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.
5. An exception list—to be discussed later.
6. The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code, including the declaration of local variables, goes here.

More to read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your method signatures.
they should be like this:
public void setAge(int age) {  }
public int getAge() {  }

You missed the types.
I advice you to check this [core java tutorial](http://www.how-to-program-in-java.com/core-java-tutorial/).
it is well explained.